# What is Master Data?

Tags: ssis, integration, etl

This is a terminology question in the context of business intelligence, ETL data integration, and data warehousing.

I've always learned that the data warehouses have transactional "fact tables" which reference "dimension tables". However, some other people are using the term "master data". Does this have a different meaning in the context of ETL and data warehousing and is it equivalent to "dimension tables"?

Comment: I would ask the person using the term:   "What do you mean by 'Master Data'?"

Comment: I think they are misusing the term "master data" to describe ALL dimensional tables. I just wanted to firm this up. The key of a common language is when other ETL experts or developers join the team, there will be confusion if traditional terms are misused.

Answer (score 3):

> Master data is critical business data that is shared across the enterprise and stored and used by multiple applications and systems.Typical candidates for master data are customers, locations, and products.
>
> The main driver behind using master data is the ability to consolidate and re-use. Taking the example earlier, customer data is very likely to be shared across multiple applications. Under proper master data management, this data will be consistent across these applications and reduce the redundancy of multiple tables.

The key difference between master data and the dimension tables in a data warehouse is the **purpose** of each. Dimension tables provide information about the facts while master data provides information for the business as a whole.

Keep in mind that many dimension tables could also be candidates for master data. Read more about master data management (MDM) here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190163.aspx

Comment: I think I'm beginning to understand now, a bit. Just wanted to point out though that my initial question has been edited heavily, arguably even changing the meaning. Also, I had already read the Wikipedia entry for master data before posting, but eh. ANYWAY, perhaps a concrete example is in order. Take a typical normalized database. You have phone calls with "phone line" IDs. The IDs link to a table -- that show the phone line ID, along with number, name, date created, etc. To me, this is a DIMENSIONAL table. It is, in no way, "master data".

Comment: If I'm to understand correctly, the term MASTER DATA is not about the structure of the table as it relates to a normalized database. It's more about reusability, commonality, "single point of truth", and "conformed dimensions" and happens to be a dimensional table most of the time. A perfect example is Client Info. You might have multiple applications that are linked to client IDs, yet spell names differently, addresses, etc. so a MASTER table is used to conform these dimensions. I think the issue I'm facing is colleagues are describing EVERY dimensional table as master, a conceptual mistake.

Comment: @user45867 Exactly, not all dimension tables are master data. However, the definition I provided in the answer isn't from Wikipedia, it was something I wrote that I thought would help. My apologies for missing any info in the edit though.